# Unloading a Windows Driver

Tags: memory-leaks, kmdf, wfp, network-driver, windows-driver

I am creating a Network driver using Windows KMDF Driver and Windows Filtering Platform(WFP) API.

In my driver, I am allocating memory X using `ExAllocatePoolWithTag()` and using that address in `localRedirectContext`.

I am fetching that data (`localRedirectContext`) from a user-mode application and using that data.

I have to deallocate the data after using it in user-mode application or it should be deallocated after particular time (`timeout`).

While unloading the driver, I should deallocate all the memory allocated by the driver to avoid memory leaks.

While I deallocate the allocated memory, it's throwing errors in `WinDbg` that `the caller is trying to free an incorrect Special Pool memory block` or `the address has data with different tag and size`.

How to know whether the memory has been deallocated already, or yet to deallocated?

Now, I am using a data structure to store the allocated memories with its addresses.

When I unload the driver, I am deallocating the allocated memory, but this method also throwing breakpoints due to Special Pool Access Violation and Invalid Memory Address due to double deallocation errors.

How to safely unload a driver and deallocate memories to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fwpsk/ns-fwpsk-_fwps_connect_request0 "Note  Starting with Windows 8, memory allocated for localRedirectContext will have its ownership taken by WFP, and will be freed when the proxied flow is removed."